# How to Properly Inject SignalR IHubContext to Quartz.net Job?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, quartz.net

I have a ASP.NET MVC Core project with a SignalR hub called MyHub and Quartz.net job called MyJob which could resolve all registered services but IHubContext. However, the IHubContext is successfully resolved inside all controllers.

Here is the error I get inside my JobFactory:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[MyProject.Hubs.MyHub]' while
attempting to activate 'MyProject.Jobs.MyJob'.'
```

Would someone let me know how to resolve the IHubContext inside the Quartz.net MyJob please?

Here is my JobFactory, MyHub, and MyJob:

```
    public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        protected readonly IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

        public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
            => ServiceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
            => (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        private static readonly List<string> ConnectionIds = new();

        public static bool Connected => ConnectionIds.Count > 0;

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            ConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            ConnectionIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }

    public class MyJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyJob> _logger;
        private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _context;

        public MyJob(ILogger<MyJob> logger, IHubContext<MyHub> context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```